# Static library(ARC) work on non ARC app, met error: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Xcode 4.3.2
I wrote a static library, using ARC.

When I put it into a project, and test on iOS 4.3 simulator. (base on iOS 5.1, deploy target 4.3)

If the project using ARC, it works fine.

If the project not using ARC, met errors, such as:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
>     Referenced from: /Users/cnzzmobile/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/A4EEB0A0-AC16-402C-B426-46667225F66D/test.app/test
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
>     Referenced from: /Users/cnzzmobile/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/A4EEB0A0-AC16-402C-B426-46667225F66D/test.app/test
>     Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

I searched a lot, but can't find an answer can solve this problem.

I remove jsonobjcet which only supported by iOS5, and -fobjc-arc also doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found add "-fobjc-arc" at "other linker flag" can solve this problem on Xcode 4.3.2 based on iOS 5.1. Because the xcode can't find the lib which support ARC to link.

Notice that: add "-fobjc-arc" at "other linker flag" not at "Compile sources".

But this still doesn't work on old version Xcode 4(snow leopard) based on iOS 4.3.

I found some lib can work on both ARC and non ARC project without adding any special setting. I'm still waiting for the answer how to do this. Write code using pure C?

Comment: I had this problem pop up when trying to compile a PhoneGap HelloWorld project using XCode 4.3.2, and this fixed it... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`_objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue` is a function of iOS 5.x's version of arc.  You are attempting to build this framework and run it on iOS 4.3, which requires you to specify and deploy it for iOS 4.x, which runs the "ArcLite" framework.